# HTML5 Force a relationship between two separate elements

Tags: html, tags

I am trying to use HTML5s best practices but have the following dilemma. I have a series of images and text that related to each other but because of an application of a jQuery transition to cycle through them I have had to separate the image from its coinciding text. So rather than ideally looking like this:

```
<article>
    <img src="image1.png">
    <h1>Title1</h1>
    <p>Description</p>
</article>
<article>
    <img src="image2.png">
    <h1>Title2</h1>
    <p>Description</p>
</article>
```

Instead it looks like this:

```
<div id="textholder">
    <article>
        <h1>Title1</h1>
        <p>Description</p>
    </article>
    <article>
        <h1>Title2</h1>
        <p>Description</p>
    </article>
</div>
<div id="images">
    <article>
        <h1>Title1</h1>
    </article>
    <article>
        <h1>Title2</h1>
    </article>
</div>
```

This is obviously not ideal because there is now no relationship between the image and the text. I am gauging this relationship through [HTML5 outliner (h5o)](http://code.google.com/p/h5o/). Is there a way of linking a relationship between to separated tags?

Answer (score 0):

No. Rewrite the jQuery script, your original HTML is the semantically correct way to do it.